# Accessing the same object in different events

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have an array of objects that is shared between two different methods.

The onclick for button1 on my webpage calls method1, which populates the needed values for the objectArray. I need the onclick method for button2 to be able to access the same objectArray with the same data that method1 was working with.

```
using myWebReference;
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{        
    ObjectArray[] myObjects = new ObjectArray[100]; 

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        //I have nothing in here at the moment      
    }
    public void method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //myObjects[]'s values are calculated and assigned here. 
    }
    public void method2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String key = myObjects[0].value;
        //when I try to get data within myObjects here, myObjects does exist, 
    //but it is empty and I get a null reference error when I try to use its values.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to go with reading some samples and\or books about asp.net and web in general... Here you have your page class that will be recreated on each request, thus myObjects will be empty. Each button click is a new request. You need to save myObjects to some storage (and restore on pageLoad or similar event) or send it to client and than send back to server when you clicked button2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peter Repac said, you could also use the ViewState. Like this:

```
//In method1.
ViewState["MyObjectsKey"] = myObjects;
....

//In method2.
myObjects = ViewState["MyObjectsKey"];
```

Be wary of using this if `myObjects` gets quite large, as the ViewState is sent with the page, so bloating its size could impact performance. More info about ViewState [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Comment: It could be stored in session being saved and retrieved on each postback causing less performance impact.

Comment: That's true, but the data could be lost if the session is InProc and the application pool recycles.

Comment: Yes, thats also true. The Viewstate would be lost and so would the other Session data. Probably causing an automatic user logoff, on that stage, the lost viewstate data would be the minor problem.

Comment: I don't have very much data in myObjects. I was able to implement ViewState successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not problem of the language. Its bound to web forms.
After every web request is finished all state is destroyed on the web server.

So:
  On web request 1 you call method1 and your array is filled.

web request 1 finished html is returned to browser and array on server is destroyed.

On web request 2 method2 is called, but array is only initialized by the line

```
ObjectArray[] myObjects = new ObjectArray[100];
```

so no other data is in it.

If you want to be able to reach "previous" myObjects value you should save it somewhere, e.g in SessionState as Abe suggested, in DB, in view state, in cookie, ....

Comment: I was not aware that this was what was happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data available across different post backs you will need to either load that data the same way on each post back, or possibly store the data in session state (or some other acceptable place) once it is loaded the first time.

You can read up on session state [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Be sure to read up on the potential pitfalls of using session state.

Your code could end up looking something like this:

```
myObjects = LoadMyObjects();
Session["objects"] = myObjects;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a method where you load the array, and call it when you press button1 and call it when you press button2 also. But on action2 you will later do more stuff...

If you are just beginning I don't think is a good idea to start messing with viewstate or sessions because they can create some bad habits. The easiest approach IMHO, is to load the array twice.

You can even call method1 from method2 without creating another method.

Comment: It is actually relative. The array creation could be a performance killer and therefore creating it once and persisting it would be much better. However, this is not necessarily the case. I'm just making a valid point.

Comment: I know, but I have worked with some asp.net beginners and the worst you can teach them is sessions until they are more prepared. :-)

Comment: Definitely agree. I've seen this kind of concepts being misused by beginners because in most cases they don't fully understand the whole purpose each concept and when to use each one of them. However, experience have been the best teacher they can possibly have.